# How do I hide the header in a WPF Expander?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a business requirement that when the user clicks a series of checkboxes in a WPF application that it will show panels depending upon what checkboxes they select.  I would like to use the expander panel but I am not sure how to hide the header.  The user should not be allowed to see it unless they check the checkbox.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via making a custom [Style for your Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296.aspx).

However, it might be easier to just place the controls in a different panel, and set it's visibility to Collapsed in response to the check box state.  The main reason to use Expander is specifically to have the header and controls.

Comment: I am new to WPF.  I didn't realize the collapsed option existed off the visibility.  Thanks!

Comment: @Greg: No problem.  Collapsed is nice since it hides and removes the space of the item - perfect for your situation.

Comment: For anyone who is stumbling across this... and is then wondering "How do I remove a control from an Expander?"... Do `expander.Content = null;`

Answer (score 2):

While not the *ideal* approach you could go this route...

```
    <Expander>
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}, Mode=FindAncestor}, 
                 Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">My Expander</TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
    </Expander>
```

...where `BoolToVisibilityConverter` is something like...

```
    public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Fortuitously, WPF already has a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) class built in. Nothing wrong with demonstrating an example, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer has all that you need: [WPF Expander Button Styled so it is inside Expander Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889778/wpf-expander-button-styled-so-it-is-inside-expander-header)

If you use the style he mentions and set no header content, the header disappears